# A better way to spot spam edits introducing spurious links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, spam

There are a number of users who edit questions inserting links into the original question to completely unrelated resources. For example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26296255/revisions).

Revision 2 introduces two links to a third party site that have no relation to the question and are **nearly impossible** to spot if reviewing using side by side rendered view.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Whereas, when viewing side-by-side markdown it's much easier to spot the new (unrelated) links:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I wonder whether it might be possible to make it more obvious in all views (inline/side-by-side/side-by-side Markdown) when an edit introduces or changes a link in the question?

Comment: Nice spot. You might want to refrain to linking to the specific question, to prevent people from going medieval on the spammer's behind. Though now it doesn't matter anymore, as the link will be accessible through the edit history.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah - good point. I made sure the screenshots didn't have the url or user in it but completely overlooked the link. D'oh!

Comment: I do hope you flagged this specific case (which I just did). The user also had a similar edit on at least one other question, and potentially on others in the past - I've only checked his 5 last suggestions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suggested this [a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222385/167646), here's the response:

> This was solved by [forcing the Markdown diff view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230281/115866) in the review interface if a link was changed (and adding a link counts as a change there).

I think it is an adequate solution. The reviewers who approved the edit are entirely at fault here, it's very obvious that those links were added.

Comment: I wonder how many people just think "I never review in Markdown mode! Stupid SO" *click inline/side-by-side* and then don't see that the link is changed/added.

Comment: @RobH good point, perhaps there should be a message indicating why the markdown view is forced.

Comment: @Stijn although I question whether or not the robo-reviewers (who are the real problem) would read that message

Comment: @Dannnno: Would it be possible to have the system generate fake bad edits to present to potential robo-reviewers as a way to catch and ban these reviewers?